# Problems installing a Django app using virtualenvwrapper and pip

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am relatively new to Django, and I must admin I'm getting confused (not to mention frustrated) with its frankly, bizarre folder structure - and the differentiation between website, projects, apps and modules.

I am trying to install and use [django-realestate](http://django-real-estate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage) into my virtenv (using virtualenvwrapper)

After I created the new virtenv, I installed the Django app in the new environment. The problem is that the entire codebase is actually created under `~./virtualenvs/myenv`

The problem is that I want to be able to modify and (quite extensively) extend the code to suit my own purposes. However, I can't do that - if the code is under the "control" of virtualenv. My gut instinct is to do either of the following:

1. Move the code from the src folder under `~./vitualenvs/myenv` to `/path/to/proj`
2. Create a brand new Django install and add(/merge?) the folders `realestate`, `testproject` and `test` to my project folder?

It is a hideously complicated setup for what is a straightforward requirement: I want to have the latest Django version, and also have the code for the latest real-estate app (which I will modify extensively).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What you are suggesting is a rather bad idea and will break your ability to update Django in the future. The normal way of extending functionality onto parts of Django or django-realestate is to create a new class and inherit from whatever you want to extend.

Comment: @EmettSpeer I think you got the wrong end of the stick. I will be installing Django in my virtualenv using pip - so nothing changes there, as far as Django is concerned; It's django-realestate  that I will be modifying extensively - essentially, I'm using it as a starting point (I won't mind too much if I "fork irrevocably" from the django-realestate code base).

Comment: That makes more sense. I would suggest just forking it on github and maintaining your own version of it then.